# Add blank space to a string when outputting in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I want to add **blank space** in a string. For example: `name` is a variable that equal to `"abcxyzdefg"`.

Now, I want to print this string as: `abc xyz defg`

I used this program

```
program name_space
    implicit none
    character(len=30) :: name = "abcxyzdefg"

    write(*,3) name
    3 format (A3, 2X, A3, 2X, A4)

end program
```

I want output as:

```
abc xyz defg
```

But, I am getting by this way:

```
abc
```

Answer (score 2):

You must refer to the appropriate substrings

```
write(*,3) name(1:3), name(4:6), name(7:)
```

with just doing `write(*,'(A3,1X,A3,...)') name` the first descriptor prints the first three characters of `name` and then the output list is finished, there are no more items to be printed, so the write statement terminates.

Answer (score 1):

With the output statement

```
write(*,3) name
```

we are treating `name` as a single transfer item, processed by the `A3` format.   This `A3` format prints the first three characters for the string.

There's no further processing that can be done which transforms the item to a desirable form.

Instead, we may want to have three different transfer items.  One way is as in the [answer by Vladimir F](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55403027/3157076), to use individual substrings:

```
write(*,3) name(1:3), name(4:6), name(7:10)
write(*,3) (name(i:i+2), i=1,4,3), name(7:)  ! Can use implied do if desired
```

We can also split name in some way to get an array (if the elements are the same length that we know).  As an array, each element forms an individual output item:

```
write(*,3) TRANSFER(name, 'aaa', 3)
write(*,'(3A4)') split_into_chunks_of_4(name)
```

or we can transform the string to add spaces and then output that:

```
write(*,'(A)') split_into_chunks(name)  ! for some suitable function
```

For the case of the question, Vladimir F's answer is the best approach.  In other cases there are many options.

---

As the more general case of inserting spaces into a string hides much of the hard work, it's perhaps only fair to give an indication of an approach:

```
! Add spaces to a string str at the breakpoints bps
function split(str, bps)
  character(*), intent(in) :: str
  integer, intent(in) :: bps(:)
  character(LEN(str)+SIZE(bps)) :: split
  integer i
  split=''
  split(1:bps(1)-1) = str(1:bps(1)-1)
  do i=1, SIZE(bps)-1
    split(bps(i)+i:bps(i+1)-1+i) = str(bps(i):bps(i+1))
  end do
  split(bps(i)+SIZE(bps):) = str(bps(i):)
end function
```